# VS2008 Load Testing - Page Response Time

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, load-testing

I am running a load test from VS 2008 on my asp.net web application. The thing I notice is that for some of my pages *Average Page Time* is around 20.

Does this mean it takes 20 seconds for the server to render the page before it sends the request? Or is it simply 20 seconds until the whole page is fully loaded on the client's browser?

Does this statistic take Network Type into an account; so say that I change from 52kbps to 1.5mbps, is this statistic supposed to change?

Another thing is - my Average Response Time is 0.21, whilst some pages have Average Page Time at 20. Why is it so different? What does each mean?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Average Page Time usually just includes the time to receive all of the bytes over the network. So yeah, maybe this will change on a different bandwidth.

EDIT: As for your second question, Average Response Time is just the statistic for ALL requests that are filed during the duration of the test.

Comment: I have the the same question.. and seems hard to understand them. Can you point some me to the details somewhere?