# What exactly is Page Response Time?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, load-testing

I use Visual Studio 2012 for doing some load testing in our web application, and one of the metrics we rely on is "Page Response Time". I found [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404705%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) article, but it doesn't really answer the question. I also found a Stack Overflow question that gives some [details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/984599/vs2008-load-testing-page-response-time), but isn't quite what I'm looking for.

The software I'm testing is a web interface that uses a relational database back-end. If I look at the `Total Average Page Response Time` for a specific test, what exactly is that telling me?

Does it take into account the time that the database spent processing the request? Or just the time that the web page took to be processed on the web server and client machine?

Ultimately, I'm looking for a metric that would tell me the total response time and would also take into account time spent within SQL finding the information.

Comment: The page response time is the time between the request (from the load-test client) and the response (to the load-test client) - this includes all time spent fulfilling the request. "*Response Time*: The average time to receive the entire response to a request, measured from the time the request was sent to the Web server. The units are seconds."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the time that takes to server to send all resources (or the time to send the last one) to client browser (this is why is bandwidth dependent). for example in the picture you can see the stack overflow response time (big red line) using chrome developer tool (press f12)[image: stack overflow resource striming time -]

Comment: So if I'm understanding this properly (I did hit F12 to see it myself, that's an interesting feature), the timer for Page Response Time starts when my user's last request goes through, and ends when the server finishes sending the resources to the client browser.

Comment: Yes exactly. I have used google page speed (https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/) in order to realize some  best web practices.